# .bat file to change windows password

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe, passwords

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1FjH.png)

Is there a way to automate the process of changing the windows password using a  .bat file.
The traditional way of changing the password will be like.
Open Command Prompt, type `net user Username *` > press Enter key > Type New Password and Retype the New Password to confirm.

Comment: You can put that exact command as a one liner in a .cmd or .bat file and it does the same. Instead of *, you can also put in a password, and then it just sets that password upon doubleclicking. Given it is that easy, is that all you need to know, or is there anything else?

Comment: @LPChip No, I have tried this before this doesn't work. If I use net user Admin newpassword. It displays this... `The syntax of this command is:

NET USER
[username [password | *] [options]] [/DOMAIN]
         username {password | *} /ADD [options] [/DOMAIN]
         username [/DELETE] [/DOMAIN]
         username [/TIMES:{times | ALL}]
         username [/ACTIVE: {YES | NO}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
@echo off
net session >nul 2>&1 || (powershell start -verb runas '"%~0"' &exit /b)
net user {Username} {NewPassword}
```

Change {Username} by the username which password you would like to change and {NewPassword} with the new password.

Comment: No, I tried this is not working

Comment: @Durai: do you have an admin account?

Comment: Thanks, @Ricardo. This command works for me with admin rights `net user Administrator Newpassword@123`.The issue was with the password field. In windows server's the password field must contain - Uppercase letters, Lowercase letters, Numerals, and symbols